# Handsontable how to read cell values inside cells: function (row, col, prop) function

Tags: jquery, cell, handsontable, tr

I have a handsontable in which I am using the function

```
cells: function (row, col, prop) {
      var cellProperties;

      //Read values

        return cellProperties;
      }
    }
```

I have `5 rows and 4 columns`.

I want to read the values `R1C4, R1C4, R1C3,R1C4`. Inside the function `cells: function (row, col, prop)`.

How can I read cell values using `cells: function (row, col, prop)`

Answer (score -1):

```
cells: function (row, col, prop) {
  var cellProperties;
  //Read values
  var someVar = this.getData(1, 4, 1, 4); //getData take data from an init to an end, just like select cells in Excel
  console.log(someVar);
  return cellProperties;
  }
}
```

Use *this* to call any function for HandsOnTables.
For more information you should go to [Docs #getData](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.22.0/Core.html#getData/)